# Define the size of a window based on its inner content

Tags: c#, xaml, window

I have a window that contains a list of objects, those displayed as some `ItemsControl`.
I would like to set the window:

- the height to 2 rows of that `ItemsControl` when shown
- the width of the window to the width of the rows

Would you know how to do this dynamically?

```
<Border>
    <DockPanel LastChildFill="True" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
        <WrapPanel DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Grid.Row="1">
            <Button Content="Confirm" Command="{Binding ConfirmCommand}" />
            <Button Content="Cancel" Command="{Binding RejectCommand}" />
        </WrapPanel>
        <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
            <ItemsControl Grid.Row="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Confirmations}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ConfirmationListTemplate}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
        </ScrollViewer>
    </DockPanel>
</Border>
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

In your xaml, put names for the controls. For example I am adding name for border here,

```
<Border x:Name="MainBorder">
     ....
</Border>
```

In your code behind, do something like this.

```
public Constructor()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    // You can set width height here,
    this.Width = MainBorder.ActualWidth;
    this. Height = MainBorder.ActualHeight;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For most controls, you can set it's height and width to "Auto" in the XAML, and it will size to fit its content.

Or else you can try the method which is explained by Faisal Hafeez.

Comment: Thanks but as explained in the question, I wish to limit the height of the control to couple of displayed rows only from the ItemsControl